# Выбор строк, начинающихся с определенного символа

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то метод или способ из некоторого количества строк выбрать только те, что начинаются с определенного символа?

Например, у меня есть следующее:

```
>> Тело вопроса 1

? Вопрос 1 ?

$ Ответ 1
$ Ответ 2
$ Ответ 3
$ Ответ 4

>> Тело вопроса 2

? Вопрос 2 ?

$ Ответ 1
$ Ответ 2
$ Ответ 3
$ Ответ 4
```

А мне нужно вытащить только ответы (т.е. здесь: все то, что наинается с символа $ и до следующего символа $)

Comment: Нужно больше информации, методы могут быть -> поиск подстроки, регулярные выражения, построчное чтение или сплит по символу перевода строки \n. Какие входные данные, которые вы читаете? Тип данных

Comment: датафрейм со str

Comment: если это датафрейм, то покажите, как он выглядит.  пока это похоже на текстовый файл.